# Ubuntu doesn't wake up from suspend/sleep - Lenovo Yoga Slim 7

Tags: 20.04, amd-graphics

I am using a Lenovo Yoga Slim 7 that has trouble waking up from suspend/sleep. I've tried a lot of solutions, including:

- switching lightdm/gdm3
- updating drivers
- many other things that I even don't understand

The notebook has an AMD graphics card with the following details:

```
Device-1: AMD Renoir vendor: Lenovo driver: amdgpu v: kernel bus ID: 03:00.0 
 Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: amdgpu,ati 
           unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: AMD RENOIR (DRM 3.41.0 5.13.0-35-generic LLVM 10.0.0) 
           v: 4.6 Mesa 20.0.5 direct render: Yes
```

What can I do to fix the wake issue?

Comment: Often a video issue what video card and drivers are you using? What kernel as well.

Comment: Kernel: 5.13.0-35-generic, GPU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir (rev c1)

Comment: Kernel driver: amdgpu

Comment: Getting there was is the exact model of the video card. You have only given the company that makes it.

Comment: I added the info to the post.

Comment: I [answered](https://askubuntu.com/a/1418046/1086836) a similar question. If that works for you, please comment here for future reference.

Comment: Can't check it now, I reinstalled the system, seems to work now.

Comment: @shardulc tried on yoga slim 7 14ARE05 but no success (ubuntu 22.04). I'm using the latest bios version. Maybe mating had success to fix it?